# Is the north pole at Antarctica?

Tags: earth, earth-like, worldbuilding-resources

If opposite magnetic poles attract

```
North<===>South 

South<===>North
```

Whys is the geographic North Pole called a magnetic South Pole?

Comment: This is done to confuse alien invaders.  Any species ornery enough to still be invading other worlds will stop to argue about which hemisphere they are supposed to land in.  This will give us enough time to upload a virus into their mothership.  With tech support 10,000 light-years away, they won't want to pay the long-distance charges and will just call the whole thing off.

Comment: Because some people read Wikipedia when they're curious. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Magnetic_Pole.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this is related to world-building, but I'll provide an answer for posterity.

Earth's North Magnetic Pole (take note of the capitalisation - it's a proper noun) is actually a magnetic south pole.

By convention, we **say** that the north poles on our compass needles point North (again, note the capitalisation).

Now, let's consider this question:

> Q: What attracts the north pole of a magnet?
>
> A: The south pole of a larger magnet.

Comment: The magnet doesn't have to be larger.  The north pole of a magnet, and the south pole of another magnet exert an equal force on one another just as two masses exert equal gravitational forces on one another.  It's just that the Earth has a lot more inertia than a compass so the magnetic and gravitational effects of the Earth on the compass are a lot more noticeable than those of the compass on the Earth.

Comment: If you believe the question to be off topic, **then please don't answer it.** Instead, vote to close or flag as off topic, as appropriate. If you believe the question is a better fit on another site, then comment and/or flag for moderator attention and suggest migration to another site in the network. Answering risks encouraging posting further low-quality or off-topic questions, reducing the usefulness of the site.